# declarative pipeline with Active choice parameter

Tags: jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I tried to search anywhere but I didn't know even what to look.

I want to enable pipeline parameters only if some checkbox is checked.
I know there are plugins such as the Active Choices parameter and Active Choices Reactive parameter, but I can't figure out how.

for example, this is my snippet:

```
parameters {

        booleanParam(name: 'standalone', defaultValue: false, description: '')        
        string(name: 'OS', defaultValue: '', description: '')
    }
```

In case of standalone is true, the OS var will be available to the user.

thank
Hezi